# Improve DensityHistogram running speed and return the density array

Tags: plotting

I want to plot lots of coordinate values with **DensityHistogram** function, such as:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {100000, 2}];
DensityHistogram[data, 50]
```

When the bin number is small, it will run fast, but as I have hundreds of thousands of coordinate data, I want to give a bigger bin number (maybe `DensityHistogram[data, 1000]`), which will be very slow or crash.

(In my real case, hundreds of thousands of data will form a specific shape)

I have another question is how to get the density matrix
(**DensityHistogram** will give a density image, I think it can save time when replot it by **ArrayPlot** next time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found **HistogramList** can return the density array, and then use **ArrayPlot** plot is faster.